# Redirection After Form Validation

Tags: jquery

I have a form which I want to redirect to success page once my jQuery completes the form validation.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  if ($("#employeeID").val() == "") {
    $("#message1").html("Employee ID can't be null");
  }
  if ($("#password").val() == "") {
    $("#message2").html("Password can't be null");
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="loginform" method="post" class="login-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="employeeID">EmployeeID</label><input type="text" name="employeeID" id="employeeID" placeholder="employeeID" class="form-control" /><span id="message1"></span><br>
    <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" /><span id="message2"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
    <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="/validationSpringMVC/createAccount.html">Create an account</a></p>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever JQuery completes the form validation use following to redirect to success page

```
window.location.replace("https://www.websitename.com/success-page"); //this is just a example
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yup.. we can :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $("#submit").click(function(){ 

      if($("#employeeID").val()== ""){
         $("#message1").html("Employee ID can't be null");
         return false;
      } 

      if($("#password").val()== ""){
         $("#message2").html("Password can't be null");
         return false;
      }
      window.location.replace("https://yourdomain/successpage");
   }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to handle [onsubmit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) event instead of event of click on the submit button. You could set URL of success page within `action` argument of the form. If submit event handler returns `false` the submit action will be cancelled. Otherwise request will sent to specified URL.

```js
$("form").submit(function() {
  var hasError = false;
  $(".has-error, .has-success").removeClass("has-error").removeClass("has-success");
  if ($("#employeeID").val() == "") {
    $("#employeeID").closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    hasError = true;
  } else {
    $("#employeeID").closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
  }
  if ($("#password").val() == "") {
    $("#password").closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
    hasError = true;
  } else {
    $("#password").closest(".form-group").addClass("has-success");
  }
  return !hasError;
});
```

```css
.form-group:not(.has-error) .error-message {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="loginform" method="post" class="login-form" action="https://stackoverflow.com/users/9108771/yuvaraj-pn">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="employeeID">EmployeeID</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="employeeID" id="employeeID" placeholder="employeeID" class="form-control" />
    <span id="message1" class="help-block error-message">Employee ID can't be null</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" />
    <span id="message2" class="help-block error-message">Password can't be null</span>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
  <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="/validationSpringMVC/createAccount.html">Create an account</a></p>
</form>
```

See also [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) method documentation.

I also corrected your HTML. In above code the handler of form submit event applies [validation states](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-control-validation) on form controls in depend on the input values. The error messages visibility are controled by additional CSS rule. The handler prevent from sending if even one of the input is empty.